# iOS9で画面回転時に簡単にステータスバーの表示／非表示に追従できる方法はあるのでしょうか？

Tags: swift

iOS9で新規にプロジェクトをつくった場合
ランドスケープにするとステータスバーが非表示になりますが、
ビューコントローラーのviewの表示をこれに追従させるには、
ポートレイトとランドスケープを検知して、
viewのフレームを調整しなければならないのでしょうか？

あるいは、
もっと簡単にステータスバーの表示／非表示に
対応できる方法があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoLayoutを使ってViewを配置していれば、デバイスの回転やステータスバーの表示／非表示に合わせて、自動的に、制約を満たす形でViewの位置・サイズが決まります。わざわざ、自力で調整する必要はありません。

逆に言うと、AutoLayoutで実現できないような配置を行う場合は、すべて自力で調整することになります。